# Prime numbers with input from keyboard

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write a program in java, that allows the user to determine number (quantity) of prime numbers, that he wants to be displayed.
I have managed to write a program, in which user can specify the maximum prime number.
Can I please have some tips?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumbers{
    public static void main(String[] agrs){

    int max;

    Scanner sk = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many prime numbers you want to display? ");
    max = sk.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Prime numbers: ");

    for(int x =2; x <= max; x++){
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for(int y = 2; y < x; y++){
            if(x % y == 0){     
                isPrime = false;
                break; 
        }
        }if (isPrime){
            System.out.print(x + " ");  
    }

} System.out.print("...");
}
}
```

If i.e I put as a user 5, I get only 2,3, 5
But I want the result to be: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11

Comment: I think you mean the user specifies the number of primes to print, which is how I answered it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track the number of primes you have printed, which is not x. Check whether you have printed enough.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumbers{ public static void main(String[] agrs){

int max;
int numPrinted=0;
Scanner sk = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many prime numbers you want to display? ");
max = sk.nextInt();

System.out.print("Prime numbers: ");

for(int x =2; numPrinted < max; x++){
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for(int y = 2; y < x; y++){
        if(x % y == 0){     
            isPrime = false;
            break; 
    }
    }if (isPrime){
        System.out.print(x + " "); 
        numPrinted++; 
}

} System.out.print("...");

} }
```

Comment: @KejP . Ubetcha. I suspect where you say agrs you mean args. Also, if you like the answer, please accept it.